# Spell check with CAPS using Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I’ve noticed that Sublime Text 3 seems to ignore CAPITALISED words when using the spell checker.

Quite a lot of my document has strings in caps. I don’t want to mess with the formatting, just check the spelling.

Is there a file I can modify to toggle spell check where capitals are involved in SublimeText3?

I realise this may get thrown out for not being a coding question but I'll show you a Venn diagram of those who use SO and those who know how to really use Sublime Text.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like Vim, Emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic. This question is on-topic both here and on [su].

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, you can spell-check words in all caps, but it's going to take some effort. There is a setting that is appropriate here:

```js
// Word list to use for spell checking. May also be a list of dictionaries.
"dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic",
```

The included dictionaries (there is one for `en_US` and one for `en_GB`) include some words in all caps, such as AIDS and DNA, but not all, so you'll need to make your own `.dic` file. Fortunately, this is fairly straightforward. You'll need to extract the original file, convert it to upper case in Sublime, save it, then change your settings to point to both dictionaries.

To extract the dictionary package, install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control. Open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on macOS), type in `prv`, make sure `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package` is selected, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Next, select the `Language - English` package, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again when it shows `Start Extraction (1 of XX items selected)`. A little popup should come up telling you the package was extracted successfully.

Next, you'll need to navigate to the correct folder and open the dictionary file in Sublime. Select **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** (macOS: **`:Sublime Text → Preferences → Browse Packages…`**) to open the `Packages` directory in your file manager:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
- macOS/OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` or `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

<sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>

Once in `Packages`, navigate into the `Language - English` directory and open either `en_US.dic` or `en_GB.dic` (depending on your locale and preference) in Sublime. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (macOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) to Select All. Next, select **`Edit → Convert Case → Upper Case`** and all letters will be capitalized. Finally, select **`File → Save As…`**. Navigate up one level from `Language - English` to `Packages`, then go into the `User` directory and save the file there as `en_US_CAPS.dic` or `en_GB_CAPS.dic`, depending on which original you opened.

Finally, select **`Preferences → Settings`** and add the following to your user settings on the right side:

```js
"dictionary": ["Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic", "Packages/User/en_US_CAPS.dic"],
```

Change both occurrences of `US` to `GB` if that's what you're using. Save, and you should be all set.

---

If you want to clean up a little at the end, you can delete the `Packages/Language - English` folder that was created earlier, but things should be just fine if you don't.